# Browsers don't seem to use GPU for WebGL in Arch Linux with Nvidia Driver

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webgl, nvidia, archlinux

I am running Arch Linux (EndeavourOS) with a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080. Hardware acceleration seems to work when I run programs like games from steam. I get good frame rates for them but WebGl performance in Firefox, Chrome and Brave are all very slow.

Additionally when I run nvidia-smi, I see the non-browser processes like games appear in the process list but no browsers even when they are running WebGL.

So I guess my questions are

1. Should the browsers appear in the nvidia-smi process list if they are using the nvidia GPU?
2. If they aren't in that list does that mean they are not using the Nvidia GPU?
   3  If so how do I get the browsers using the Nvidia GPU?

For more info: here is gist of the output of chromes about://gpu in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/stuartlynn/63c937c7d24ba017679d56dc1735481c)

I am running nvidia driver version 460.67

I am not using bumble or any GPU switching tools, just straight Nvidia.

I have tried playing around with settings in Chrome and Firefox but to no effect.

Comment: I should also mention that this isn't a problem if I boot up in to windows on the same machine. All WebGL performance there is as expected

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, hardware WebGL support in chrome was limited, you need to investigate further on that, i think there was a blacklist or some sort of limitation you can change. About firefox, recently they've enabled hw WebGL support, but you need to be running above version 75 and exclusively on Wayland.